How to Dynamically Adjust CSS for YouTube Video Orientation?
I'm working on a project where I display a series of YouTube videos stored in a JavaScript array retrieved from my database. Each video has a known orientation (portrait or landscape). I've made some adjustments to my CSS to ensure that the videos utilize the full viewport without any margins, as shown below:
.fancybox-content {
  width: 99.1vw !important; 
  height: 99.1vh !important; 
}

.fancybox-slide {
   padding: 0px !important;
}

While this works for landscape videos, I'm facing issues with portrait videos (YouTube Shorts) not displaying correctly. I want to ensure that portrait videos fill the screen properly on mobile devices, while landscape videos should maintain a width of 100%.
What would be the best approach to dynamically adjust this CSS based on the video orientation? Are there any JavaScript or CSS solutions that can help achieve this? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

If you know what aspect ratio each of your videos has, you can add a data-custom-class attribute to your links with a CSS class that would target portrait videos.
